# How do you connect an external database on phonegap through ios?

Tags: ios, database, cordova

I am trying to connect a database to my iphone app (I'm using phonegap to code). Would anyone provide a sample code for connecting a database? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it using Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```